# Show as much elements as it can render without overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a long list of tags, let say 20 tags, I want to show as many tags(widgets) in a row as a device can render with its screen width. Let say that the device renders 3 tags in the row without overflowing, but the forth is just half rendered, so I want to hide all overflowing tags from 4 to 20 and show three dots, so something like text ellipsis but with widgets. And I need to know how many elements are overflowing (the three dots are opening a menu which shows all the other tags). The tags have different width based on the text which is inside them.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't builtin solution for that. There are multiple approach to solve this problem. What about that three dots functionality? What will it do? Is it clickable to expand row?

Comment: I tried the wrap solution, mentioned under,  I tried somehow to precalculate the item width but I am new in flutter, so I didn't get anywhere further than a concept I have in my mind, the three dots are opening a context menu which shows a list of non rendered tags. For now I am just showing the first tag, and then the three dots.